# variational bayes lower bound derivation for a Normal

Tags: expected-value, multivariate-normal-distribution, kullback-leibler, variational-bayes

I'm learning about variational inference and tried to follow the example for a Gaussian Mixture as described [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/dp-derivation.html).

I could follow the bound for $\phi_k$ which is the difference of two Beta log likelihoods.

But I cannot follow the example for the bound for $\mu_k$ which is the difference of two multivariate Normals.

The example is described as:
In the model $\mu_k \sim \text{Normal}(0, \textbf{I})$,
 in the variational distribution $\mu_k \sim \text{Normal}(\nu_{\mu_k}, \textbf{I})$.

The bound for $\mu_k$ is then derived in the example:

$$
E_q[\log P(\mu_k)] - E[\log Q(\mu_k)] =\\
\int\!d\mu_f q(\mu_f) \log P(\mu_f)
  - \int\!d\mu_f q(\mu_f) \log Q(\mu_f)  \\
  - \frac{D}{2}\log 2\pi - \frac{1}{2} ||\nu_{\mu_k}||^2 - \frac{D}{2}
  + \frac{D}{2} \log 2\pi e
$$

I have no idea how to get there. Why is there an integral? Is it because of the expectation? But in the Beta example above it was just the difference of the log likelihoods.

Answer (score 1):

That's right, the integral is due to the expectation. By definition:

$$\mathbb{E}_q(f(x)) \equiv \int f(x)q(x)dx$$

(Or a sum, for discrete $X$.)

In the beta case, the authors seem to employ known results for the expectation of a log-beta variable. (Note that several terms in the $\phi_k$ bound match the digamma expression for $\mathbb{E}(\ln(X))$, $X \sim Beta(\alpha, \beta)$ given in [sidebar here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution).)